# How to properly track link clicks in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have started to test Google Tag Manager and we are not best friends. On http://www.example.com/examplepage/ I have a simple link like so:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/anotherexamplepage/">My text here</a>
```

How do I trigger that click?

In "Triggers" i have created an "Click" event that targets all elements witch fires on: "click target" -> "contains" -> "http://www.example.com/anotherexamplepage/".

Then I have created a tag to Analytics witch fires on "Click" where I have selected the trigger I have created.

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards
Johan Linnarsson

Answer (score 1):

Use `"Click URL"` variable instead of `"Click target"`. Documentation: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en

> Click Element: The HTML element that was clicked.
>   Click Classes: An array of the values found in the element's class attribute.
>   Click ID: The ID attribute of the clicked element.
>   Click Target: The target attribute of the clicked element.
>   Click URL: The HREF attribute of the clicked element, if any.
>   Click Text: The visible text inside the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Click Text` equals "My text here" instead. In order to use `Click Target`, you have to have a target attribute for the auto-event element (ie. the element that was clicked). If you had like an ID or something, that would be better.